# File does not show on explorer, but VB.NET open it

Tags: c#, vb.net, explorer, fileinfo, hidden-files

My program write some files at the windows system path (C:\windows\syswow64...).

One of this files, were deleted for test reason, we're changing something and we need to delete it. OK, there's no problem here, the file is gone(almost...).
The problem is, my application still getting the file! It's fun, cause I really delete the file (shift+del)

I test if file exist with FileInfo class.

I'm going crazy with this. I can't see where is the mistake.
And sure, in Folder Options is enable to see Hidden and System Files...

Thank you

My code is bellow:

```vb
Public Shared Function GetUserConfigFile() As String
    Dim UserConfigFile As String = Metodos.GetUserConfigPath("config.gf")
    'Above we have C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Microsoft\....\config.gf

    Dim ConfigFile As New IO.FileInfo(UserConfigFile)
    ConfigFile.Refresh()

    EventLog.RegisterDebugMessage("ConfigFile.Exists:{0};ConfigFile.Length:{1}", ConfigFile.Exists, ConfigFile.Length)
    If ((ConfigFile.Exists AndAlso ConfigFile.Length = 0) OrElse Not ConfigFile.Exists) Then
        Dim config As StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(UserConfigFile)
        config.WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?><cnfg></cnfg> ")
        config.Close()
        config.Dispose()
    End If
    EventLog.RegisterDebugMessage("config.gf -> {0}", IO.File.ReadAllText(UserConfigFile))
    '''''''''''And here it's show me the content of the file... -.-''''''

    Return UserConfigFile
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you're working on the same path?

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be writing files in any system directories these days.

Comment: Yeah... I think about this before... cause we can put this file on SysWOW64 or System32... I tried both, without success.

I need write my files there.

Comment: Have you tried checking in debugger whether `UserConfigFile` contains the path you expect it to have?  Also, user config files usually don't go into system directories.

Comment: Yes. Is the same path I'm looking.
I know is not the best place, but I need it there. I can't change it.

I just tried to copy a file to path specified, and you wanna know? It was.

I'm quite sure it's little problem, but I can't see it.

Comment: UAC File virtualization?

Comment: @Camford, I guess the answer is no. It's a Virtual Machine. I'm not sure what is File Virtualization.

Comment: Oh... I forgot to say that I have other 5 files in the folder that're showed on explorer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a very similar note to what Mark Peters said, another thing that could be happening is [UAC Data Redirection](http://web.archive.org/web/20120624051235/http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx) because you do not have write permissions to that folder so what you are really seeing is files located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore\Windows\System32`. Does your application run with administrative privileges, if not, do the files go missing when it does?

I have a much longer post describing a similar issue over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/425513/windows-7-locked-files-folders/425535#425535).

As an aside why do you "*need*" to have your program be accessing files in the windows directory? What are you doing that adds that requirement to your program?

Comment: Exactly what was happening! Thank you! You kill the ghost! lol

The application we are developing need to be hidden from the user. You wanna think that's a virus or something like that, everybody does. But it's not. Its a tool to collect some information to help the administrator manage the employee, who cannot stop the tool.

Comment: You should be running it as a system service and use group policy to prevent the user from disabling the service.

Comment: Yeah, I know that the way we're doing is not the best.
We're going to change it to a service or driver... but now we need to fix things up.
Thank you again.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  That explains the differences.  I love SO because I learn something new every single day.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you are being hit by the file system redirector ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\lastgood\system32 is redirected to %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\regedit.exe is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe.

There's some magic that happens with the System32 and SYSWOW64 folders.
(Ironically,the 32-bit files are stored in WOW64 and the 64-bit files are stored in System32)

The MSDN page suggests a posible solution:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access. This mechanism is flexible and easy to use, therefore, it is the recommended mechanism to bypass file system redirection. Note that 64-bit applications cannot use the Sysnative alias as it is a virtual directory not a real one.

Comment: Interesting... but I think is not my case, I direct access SYSWOW64 folder. Am I right?

Comment: Surely if redirection was at play then both the read and the write would be redirected to the same location, negating the error reported?

Comment: @Matt You would think so, but it sure smells like a redirection problem to me